# How to show, and collect, all system information in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Guessing how to get it simply and quickly, I did write down a little BASH batch program.
To use it, simply copy the code below and paste it in your text editor, save it in a file named at your taste in you **~/bin** folder, and don't forget to make it **executable**.

It firstly collects infos from several commands (`uname`, `lsblk`, etc...) output, then it organizes them to show in the terminal window.

It offers also to get those information in a text file, for further use, if launched from terminal window, not if launched from ALT+F2 dialog.

Note that for XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP env varianle and `xfce4-about`, you probably need to substitute it with a command of your own desktop environment.

I hope this will be helpful for eneryone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ---------------- clear window
clear
# ----------------set color vars
    export CYoGY="\e[1;34;40m"
    export CYoBK="\e[1;34;34m"
    export BLoGY="\e[1;34;40m"
    export BLoBK="\e[0;34;34m"
    export YEoBK="\e[1;30;33m"
    export YEoGY="\e[1;33;40m"
    export WHoGY="\e[7;37;40m"
    # ---------------- save current prompt
    export oldprompt=$PS1
    printf "$BLoGY"
    echo -ne $CYoGY
    printf "\e[1;1H-------------------------- GG procedure -----------------------\n"
    #--------------- initialize system specs vars
    export HostNode=$(hostnamectl)"\n"
    export Tnode=$(uname --nodename)"$BLoGY - which FQDN is $YEoBK $(hostname -f)$YEoBK "
    export Tkernel=$(uname -s)    ### print the kernel name
    export Tkrel=$(uname -r)      ### print the kernel version
    export Tkver=$(uname -v)      ### print the kernel release
    export Tmachhw=$(uname -m)    ### print the machine hardware name
    export Tproctyp=$(uname -p)   ### print the processor type
    export Thwplat=$(uname -i)    ### print the hardware platform
    export Theos=$(uname -o)      ### print the operating system
    #
    export Thedesk="$(echo $DESKTOP_SESSION)\t"
    export Thedesk+="$(env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP)"
    export XfceV="$(xfce4-about -V | grep about)"
    #
    export TheHW=$(lshw -disable isapnp -c cpu -c video -c network -short -quiet)
    #
    export SysRel1=$(lsb_release -cs)
    export SysRel2=$(lsb_release -is)
    export SysRel3=$(lsb_release -ds)
    export SysRel4=$(lsb_release -rs)
# ---------------- launch terminal window
    xterm -T "System ID" +cm -fa "Monospace" -fs "12" -geometry "90x51+450+5" -bw "0" -e '
    # ---------------- go showing results, printing labels firstly
    #
    printf "$WHoGY\e[1;1H**** Actual system ***************************** \e[0m"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[2;10H Host Node            $YEoGY\e[2;20H$HostNode"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[11;1H node hostname is:    $YEoGY\e[11;22H $Tnode"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[12;1H kernel version is:   $YEoGY\e[12;22H $Tkver"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[13;1H machine hardware is:     $YEoGY\e[13;22H $Tmachhw"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[14;1H processor type is:   $YEoGY\e[14;22H $Tproctyp"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[15;1H h/w platform is:     $YEoGY\e[15;22H $Thwplat"
    #--------------- show system specs on screen
    echo -ne "$CYoGY "
    printf "$WHoGY\e[17;1H**** OS SPECS ******************************** \e[0m"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[18;1H Operating system is:     $YEoGY\e[18;22H $Theos"
    printf "$YEoGY\e[19;39H $XfceV"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[19;1H Desktop env. is:     $YEoGY\e[19;22H $Thedesk"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[20;2HDistro codename:\e[20;22H$YEoGY $SysRel1"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[21;2HDistributor ID:\e[21;22H$YEoGY $SysRel2"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[22;2HDescription:\e[22;22H$YEoGY $SysRel3"
    printf "$CYoGY\e[23;2HRelease:\e[23;22H$YEoGY $SysRel4"
    #
    printf "$WHoGY\e[25;1H**** Main system devices (lshw) *********************** \e[0m"
    printf "$BLoGY\e[26;2H $YEoGY$TheHW\n"
    #
    printf    "$WHoGY\e[1B**** Block devices List (lsblk - loops excluded) ************** \e[0m"
    printf "$YEoBK\e\n$YEoGY"
    lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID -e7
#    >>--------------------------------------↑↑ exclude LOOPS block devices (7) from listing
    printf "$BLoGY----------------------------------------------------------------------------\a\e[0m\r\n"
    printf "\e[5;32;40mpress a key to terminate ..."
    read -n1 
    set PS1="$oldprompt"]
    # --- wait for a key press to terminate and close window
#   read -n1
    ' &
#*** end of command to be executed in the terminal window
###
 Answer1=""
 printf "\033[1;44;33mYou can get also an OUTPUT into a FILE\n Do you want it (y/N)? \e[0m\n"
 read -n1 Answer1
 clear
 case $Answer1 in
    [yY] ) echo -e $"\n Writing file ...";
    Tnode="node hostname is:    $(uname -n) - which FQDN is $(hostname -A)"
    Tkernel="kernel name is:      $(uname -s)"
    Tkrel="kernel-release is:   $(uname -r)"
    Tkver="kernel version is:   $(uname -v)"
    Tmachhw="machine hardware is: $(uname -m)"
    Tproctyp="processor type is:   $(uname -p)"
    Thwplat="h/w platform is:     $(uname -i)"
    Theos="operating system is: $(uname -o)"
    #
    Thedesk="desktop env. is:     $(echo $DESKTOP_SESSION) - "
    Thedesk+="$(env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP)"
    #
    SysRel1="Distributor ID:      $(lsb_release -cs)"
    SysRel2="Description:         $(lsb_release -is)"
    SysRel3="Release:             $(lsb_release -ds)"
    SysRel4="Codename:            $(lsb_release -rs)"
    # ---
    # ---------------- save current values to a file
    echo -e "saving results in 000.txt file ...."
    echo "------------------------ Actual system description ------------------------" > 000.txt
    echo "$Tnode" >> 000.txt
    echo "$Tkernel" >> 000.txt
    echo "$Tkrel"  >> 000.txt
    echo "$Tkver" >> 000.txt
    echo "$Tmachhw" >> 000.txt
    echo "$Tproctyp">> 000.txt
    echo "$Thwplat" >> 000.txt
    echo " ">> 000.txt
    echo "-------------------------------- OS specs --------------------------------">> 000.txt
    echo "$Theos" >> 000.txt
    echo "$Thedesk" >> 000.txt
    echo "$SysRel1" >> 000.txt
    echo "$SysRel2" >> 000.txt
    echo "$SysRel3" >> 000.txt
    echo "$SysRel4" >> 000.txt
    echo " ">> 000.txt
    echo "-------------------------- Main system devices ---------------------------">> 000.txt
    echo "$TheHW" >> 000.txt
    echo " ">> 000.txt
    echo "--------------------------- Block devices mount --------------------------">> 000.txt
    lsblk  -o NAME,SIZE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID >> 000.txt
    echo -e " .... 000.txt file saved, press a key to view it and finish"
    read -n1 
    ggedit 000.txt
    ;;
    * ) ;;
esac
echo -e $"\n"
Answer1=""
exit 0
#end
```

The result should seems like this:
[image]

Comment: The Ubuntu Forums has an [official system information script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/blob/main/system-info) that has quite an extended functionality - why not use that instead?